# Setting transparency of feature class in ModelBuilder in ArcMap?

Tags: arcmap, modelbuilder, transparency-opacity

I've made a model which yields an output feature class using ModelBuilder in ArcMap 10.4

I can set the symbology for the output layer by specifying a layer file.

Is there any way I can set the transparency of this output layer to a specific value directly within ModelBuilder?

Comment: A partial workaround is to add another field which stores the transparency and enable that field via Layer Properties => Symbology => Advanced => Transparency. However I could not figure out how to define the new field as indicating transparency from within ModelBuilder

Comment: Are you aware of the _Apply Symbology From Layer_ tool?

Comment: The solution is to choose the added field as indicating transparency via Layer properties => Symbology => Advanced => Transparency. Then save the symbology as layer file. You can then use the layer file in ModelBuilder and it will correctly use the added field as indicating transparency.

Comment: @Hornbydd This would be useful if you had the transparency set by another layer. However I want to delineate a new feature class from an existing feature class (which does not have transparency) and in the end apply some standard transparency from within ModelBuilder.